# Trying to create Redshift table in python using psycopg2.sql

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I'm trying to create this table in redshift via python using psycopg2:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + "<schema>.<tablename> " + \
      "( vendorid varchar(4), pickup_datetime TIMESTAMP, " + \
      "dropoff_datetime TIMESTAMP, store_and_fwd_flag varchar(1), " + \
      "ratecode int, pickup_longitude float(4), pickup_latitude float(4)," + \
      "dropoff_logitude float(4), dropoff_latitude float(4), " + \
      "passenger_count int, trip_distance float(40), fare_amount float(4), " + \
      "extra float(4), mta_tax float(4), tip_amount float(4), " + \
      "tolls_amount float(4), ehail_fee float(4), improvement_surcharge float(4), " + \
      "total_amount float(4), payment_type varchar(4), trip_type varchar(4))  " + \
      "DISTSTYLE EVEN SORTKEY (passenger_count, pickup_datetime);"
```

Schema.tablename to be entered via command line so I need a variable to hold sys.arg[0]...but how do I construct that using OR should I use psycopg2.sql??

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you want to run your python script on a command line and pass a couple of arguments that include the schema and table name of the Redshift table.

You can use the `argparse` library to parse the command line arguments into variables and then concatenate them into the sql string:

```
import argparse

...

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Parse arguments
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("schema")
parser.add_argument("table")
args = parser.parse_args()
schema_name = args.schema
table_name = args.table

...

sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + schema_name + "." + table_name + " " +\
  "( vendorid varchar(4), pickup_datetime TIMESTAMP, " + \
  "dropoff_datetime TIMESTAMP, store_and_fwd_flag varchar(1), " + \
  "ratecode int, pickup_longitude float(4), pickup_latitude float(4)," + \
  "dropoff_logitude float(4), dropoff_latitude float(4), " + \
  "passenger_count int, trip_distance float(40), fare_amount float(4), " + \
  "extra float(4), mta_tax float(4), tip_amount float(4), " + \
  "tolls_amount float(4), ehail_fee float(4), improvement_surcharge float(4), " + \
  "total_amount float(4), payment_type varchar(4), trip_type varchar(4))  " + \
  "DISTSTYLE EVEN SORTKEY (passenger_count, pickup_datetime);"
...
```

You can call your script on the command line like so:

```
python my_script.py myschema mytable
```

Comment: Well the above works but does not produce a new table.  Its like the commit does not take affect.  I'm trying to break it down...before I use command line arguments, I'm trying to create this table in redshift but nothing I do seems to work

Comment: What do you mean by "it works"? Maybe if you post the rest of your code someone might be able to help?

Comment: please see codes at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929991/trying-to-create-a-redshift-table-using-python-and-psycopg2-but-the-table-does-n?noredirect=1#comment102310602_57929991

Comment: That code doesn't explain what you mean by "it works". Do you mean the code completes without any errors? Have you tried adding a print statement around the generated `sql` value and then running the command manually on Redshift? Does that work?

Comment: it works meaning it runs and returns no errors but does not create any tables and yes i have done that, made the sql statement one line, used f-string format, and more.  So what would help me is to see someone else's codes that uses psycopg2 or psycopg2.sql model to create table in redshift with say 5 columns.